# capistrano + rails 5 : server starts in production mode instead of staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy a rails 5 app to a staging server using capistrano with nginx and passenger, however running `Rails.env` yields production instead of staging. Here's my capistrano setup:

in `config/deploy.rb`:

`set :stages, %i(staging production)
set :default_stage, :staging`

in `config/environments/staging.rb`:

`set :stage, :staging
set :rails_env, :staging`

running `echo $RAILS_ENV` in my server yields 'staging'

and my `passenger_app_env` config aso has `staging`

I'm not aware of anything that could override those, Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

PD: I'm using `rbenv`

Comment: hmm did you tried to update that env key on server to staging value?

Comment: If you mean RAILS_ENV then yes, its staging on the server

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone hits this, I ended up re-installing nginx and redoing all config files and got it working without changing anything in capistrano. So it was a setup issue.